# Extracting values from a string and store them in a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `string`

```
string = "get|Server ID:Server1,Server ID:Server2,Server ID:Server3,Query:SELECT * FROM sometable,_xsrf:57bsdkfnklbjhgfhjfghsndfsdfsdf"
```

the only thing between `get|` and `,Query:` are server IDs

in my example there are 3 server IDs but there can be more

```
string = "get|Server ID:Server1,Server ID:Server2,Server ID:Server3,Server ID:Server4,Server ID:Server5,Query:SELECT * FROM sometable,_xsrf:57bsdkfnklbjhgfhjfghsndfsdfsdf"
```

I want to select all the server IDs eg server1, server2, server3 and so on, and put them in a list.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? What are the usual patterns in the string? And don't use `str` as a variable name, it masks the built-in.

Comment: By usual patterns I mean things like: it always starts with `get|`, the `Query:` parameter could happen anywhere in the string, etc. These *matter*, one example doesn't make for a pattern.

Comment: Because if anyone answers this, with a regex, say, then suddenly you'll find that some of your input is slightly different and you come back with comments to the answer asking for an adjustment. Then you find another exception, and another. Etc. Had you done the work up front and told us more about the *types of input* to expect, then we'd not have to have that back and forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = "get|Server ID:Server1,Server ID:Server2,Server ID:Server3...,Query:SELECT * FROM sometable,_xsrf:57bsdkfnklbjhgfhjfghsndfsdfsdf"

pattern = r'Server ID:([^,.]*),?'
result = re.findall(pattern, text)

print result
```

Here is the output:

```
['Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3']
```